# removing a transitive dependency in maven

Tags: java, maven-2, slf4j, build-dependencies

I am working on porting some legacy code to a new versions . one particular module (slf4j) in which 1.5x versions are incompatible with 1.6x and 1.7x , my problem is a project that my project depends on is included as an jar in the classpath . Is there a way to get around such a problem ?

Comment: So your project depends on something that itself depends on a 1.5.x version of SLF4J? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes , I am planning to use either the 1.6x and 1.7x versions which is not backward compatible with 1.5x . Each time I make the war ( of the project I am working on ) it fails because of the incompatibility which exists due to the different versions that come into use because of the transitive dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a direct dependency in pom Maven will use it and omit any transitive dependencies to the same artifact, eg here

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

camel-core has a transitive dependency slf4j-api-1.6.6 but Maven will choose slf4j-api-1.7.5

Comment: I am not sure this is right , I tried the same thing with the newer version of slf4j added to my projects POM . it still causes compatibility issues . though this may be only for the sl4j case , I cannot say with certainty .

Comment: in Eclipse it's easy to verify go to pom "dependency hierarchy" tab

Comment: yep mvn dependency:tree is what I used to deduce how the dependencies were still sneaking in even though I had linked in a newer version to my project

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved my issue is to redeploy the project that my project depended on . Since it was a jar I had to recreate it in a maven format and add the necessary exclusion statements to stop all transitive dependencies at that level . This may not be best practice but worked in my case . I guess with the newer version of projects being all maven based exclude tags should be enough